# ng test returns Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.006 secs / 0 secs)

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

I need to update Angular from 5 to 15. I'm going to do this by updating the application one version at a time: 5 to 6, 6 to 7, ...,14 to 15. Before I do this, I need to write some test cases so I can test components after each update and see if its successful. Every time I run `ng test` I get: `Chrome 112.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.006 secs / 0 secs)`. The browser launches I get the following windows:[image]

This is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
  basePath: '',

  frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  plugins: [
    require('karma-jasmine'),
    require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
    require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
    require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
  ],
  client:{
    clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
   },
  coverageIstanbulReporter: {
     reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
     fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
  },
  angularCli: {
   environment: 'dev'
  },
  reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
  port: 9876,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  autoWatch: true,
  browsers: ['Chrome_without_security'],
  customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_without_security: {
          base: 'Chrome',
          flags: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-site-isolation-trials']
      }
  },
  singleRun: false
 });
};
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "angular-spa-web-api",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.config.js --hmr -e=hmr",
  "build:staging": "ng build --prod --env=staging",
  "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
  "@angular/common": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/core": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/flex-layout": "5.0.0-beta.15",
  "@angular/forms": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/material": "5.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/router": "5.1.0",
  "@ngrx/store": "5.1.0",
  "@schematics/angular": "^0.1.10",
  "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.2.0",
  "angular-font-awesome": "3.1.2",
  "angular-material-fileupload": "0.0.6",
  "angular-oauth2-oidc": "3.0.3",
  "angular2-csv": "0.2.5",
  "angular2-json2csv": "1.1.2",
  "angulartics2": "5.4.0",
  "core-js": "2.5.3",
  "countup.js-angular2": "6.0.2",
  "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
  "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
  "ng4-loading-spinner": "1.1.1",
  "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "5.3.1",
  "ngx-mat-select-search": "1.0.0",
  "ngx-order-pipe": "2.0.1",
  "ngx-owl-carousel": "2.0.7",
  "rxjs": "5.5.5",
  "script-loader": "0.7.2",
  "underscore": "1.8.3",
  "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
  "zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "5.1.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "8.10.64",
  "codelyzer": "4.0.2",
  "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
  "karma": "1.7.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
  "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
  "karma-script-launcher": "^1.0.0",
  "protractor": "5.2.2",
  "ts-node": "4.0.2",
  "tslint": "5.8.0",
  "typescript": "2.6.2"
 }
}
```

Here is the test file in my solution explorer:

[image]